# Mod_rewrite-htaccess: using URL variable as url prefix (sub domain)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7

I have a website which is currently developed using Drupal.
I want to use a custom URL redirect using htaccess for multilingual website.
At the moment the original url is: http://mydomain.com/page-title/?lang=en
What I want to use is something like this http://en.mydomain.com/page-title

How should I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(en).(mydomain.com)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=%1 [L,QSA]
```

So when access  http://en.mydomain.com/page-title, it will rewrite to /page-title?lang=en